# Add a number of ImageViews to the screen and Animate them independentaly

Tags: android, animation

I'm wanting to add a number of `ImageView`'s to a `RelativeLayout` or different size (always square though) and animate them independently so they "float" around the screen. I have a start on this but it's not quite right.

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1500);


    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    //animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
    Resources res = getResources();

    for (int i = 0;i < 20;i++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(150 - 50) + 50;
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, i1, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.d("Size", String.valueOf(px));
        iv.setMaxWidth((int) px);
        iv.setMaxHeight((int) px);
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) px, (int) px, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        String colour = String.valueOf(r.nextInt(999999));
        String col = ("000000" + colour).substring(colour.length());
        Log.d("Colour will be", "#"+col);

        image.eraseColor(Color.parseColor("#"+col));
        iv.setImageBitmap(image);
        //iv.back
        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.for_images)).addView(iv, 0);
    }



    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.for_images)).setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    controller.start();
```

That's what I have at the moment, but they seem to animate one after another, how can I get them to animate all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends what is the final animation you are looking for, playing with delay and the animation you can get different results. Currently you have set a delay for controller and because the views size are different the `TranslateAnimation` makes parallel effect when having to type as `RELATIVE_TO_SELF`. This might be the one you looking for:

```
animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
        0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
        set, 0);
```

Comment: The final effect I want is a bunch of differently sized and coloured square moving around behind the rest of the layout, but this may be too complex for me at the moment as this is just an idea I have, it's not essential to the app.

Comment: Did you try my answer how the visual effect was with that? I'm sure you find the proper effect changing the values there. Maybe you even end up with having all different animations for each view.

Comment: Yeah your code did make them all move at once, and I'll accept it as it fixed the problem this post is about. I think I'm going to have to read up more on how Animations actually work before trying to implement this idea as I'm going to need to keep track of if objects are out of view etc.